# Create directories and files from a template for rapid development with node/npm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to setup a shortcut to generate new components. For example if I had a bunch of React or Angular components that had a particular dir/file structure and included sample code for a new component. Is there a way to do this with node? It's quite time consuming to keep adding the same directories and files whenever I need to create a new component.

I usually do this in a convoluted but workable way with bash and aliasing but would like to use node, ie. `npm run component myNewComponent` where 'myNewComponent' would act as the function name within a myNewComponent.js file etcetc

I would have an example directory structure templated somewhere that node could pick up from or have it hardcoded in the node script file itself.

`Yeoman` does this with generators, but I would like to achieve it purely through node/node modules and full control over the code output and locations.

Comment: If the question is "can this be achieved with Node", then the answer is yes. If the question is "what library does this", you already answered it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Since I'm not on a Yeoman stack would this not be ideal, or are you saying that you can use Yeoman purely for this task alone? I had assumed Yeoman only runs these tasks if you're using one of it their generators? I hope I've understood you correctly